# C# - What is the best way to export the content of a list in an external file?

Tags: c#, excel, xml

I'm developing a program to manage my coin collection. I'd like to export my list of coins in an external file in order to save what I've stored inside the list. As the title says, I'd like to know what is the best way to do that. Should I export the content in a text file, in a Excel file or in a XML file?

I don't know if it is useful to know this, but I'm using LINQ to manage the queries.

At the moment, everything is working as intended. The only thing that I need to finish the project is to save all the data inside the list. I'm not asking for some code to paste, I just want some opinions.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You could export to a csv. There is a library called CsvHelper and makes writing CSV files very easy.

Comment: That highly depends on the complexity of your data. For simple strings and numbers a simple text-file may be enough, however when your data becomes more complex you may chose xml as well.

Comment: CSV and Text save everything as a string. With XML you can include a schema so number and dates will get read properly.

Comment: @HimBromBeere well about complexity, I need to interact a lot with the file because I need to read it in order to display my coins, or sort them by their nation for example. And of course I need to write when I need to add new coins or delete coins that I don't have anymore. There are some edit options too (edit the name for example).

Answer (score 1):

Wow, so many options!

I think these days I prefer JSON.  It is lightweight simple, human readable and portable.
With a library such as Newtonsoft then it is also easy.  I know you didn't ask for a code example, but below shows how easy it is.

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText("c:\path\outputfile.json", output);
```

And to read it in again

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("c:\path\inputfile.json");
MyObject myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject >(json);
```

And if you did want XML, you can use the sample library to then convert your obejct  to XML for output

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "RootElementName");
doc.Save("c:\path\outputfile.xml");
```

Comment: Well after I've posted the question I thought about JSON! I've used it with Unity, I had a very good experience with it. It can be my final decision. About your examples it's ok, I've appreciated them!